# python access to TimesTen

Tags: python, timesten

I googled a lot to find any python module to access TimesTen (in memory database).
I am writing a automated testing framework (more like for System Test and not Unit Test). Is anyone aware of such module? The last resort is write the wrapper myself but this is something I really want to avoid.

Comment: Did you find a solution? If you wrote the ODBC wrapper, would you mind sharing it?

Answer (score 2):

To use Python with TimesTen (11.2 or 18.1), you should use [cx_Oracle](https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/)

cx_Oracle works the same for both TimesTen and the Oracle RDBMS

cx_Oracle uses [ODPI-C](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/) which is a C library wrapper to [OCI](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/oci.html)

For both TimesTen and the Oracle RDBMS, cx_Oracle can either use the [Easy connect](https://docs.oracle.com/database/timesten-18.1/TTCDV/oci.htm#BABIBGGB)  method or [tnsnames.ora](https://docs.oracle.com/database/timesten-18.1/TTCDV/oci.htm#BABHAAHJ) in the connect string.

The following cx_Oracle example uses tnsnames.ora [ie doug/doug@sampledb]

```
# myscript.py

from __future__ import print_function

import cx_Oracle

connection = cx_Oracle.connect("doug", "doug", "sampledb")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("insert into t values (42)")
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

The direct linked and client server tnsnames.ora entries for TimesTen 18.1.2.3 sampledb is:

sampledb =(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = sampledb)(SERVER = timesten_direct)))

sampledbCS =(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = sampledbCS)(SERVER = timesten_client)))

As always, you need to source bin/ttenv.sh to configure the environment!

On my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, my PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH were:

echo $PATH
/home/ubuntu/tt18123/bin:/home/ubuntu/tt18123/install/bin:/home/ubuntu/tt18123/install/ttoracle_home/instantclient_11_2:/home/ubuntu/tt18123/install/ttoracle_home/instantclient_11_2/sdk:/home/ubuntu/.cargo/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/ubuntu/tt18123/ttclasses/lib:/home/ubuntu/tt18123/install/lib:/home/ubuntu/tt18123/install/ttoracle_home/instantclient_11_2

echo $TNS_ADMIN
/home/ubuntu/tt18123/install/network/admin/samples

Oracle TimesTen will officially support ODPI-C and cx_Oracle in TimesTen 18.1.3

Please avoid using any ODBC based python libraries with TimesTen as cx_Oracle is what Oracle Development tests and develops against.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find native one, but TimesTen has ODBC
interface that you could use.

http://www.compwisdom.com/topics/ODBC

Comment: I saw this link in other forums as well. I am aware that TimesTen has ODBC access but then I will need to write the python module myself which will call the TimesTen ODBC API. I want to avoid this due to time constraints.

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/494858-access-timesten-using-python - I think it's better to give a link to [ODBC and Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ODBC) rather than just paste some answer verbatim that links to some aggregator. @Sudeep - looks like there is no avoiding the requirement to write ODBC code, there's no module on PyPi or the net.

Answer (score 0):

There is [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) which is supposed to work on odbc databases. I'm not sure if it'll actually work. I think pyodbc requires odbc 3, and timesten might not support that (haven't checked), but it is worth checking out.

There is also [mxODBC](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxODBC/), which I have not tried. That might work as well.

Right, so here's an update since I tried it out:
(Assuming you're on some sort of unix)
It actually works with [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) together with [unixodbc](http://www.unixodbc.org/). pyodbc requires ODBC3.x and TimesTen don't support that. But, unixodbc will "translate" between the two for you. 
That means you can't use the timesten libodbc.so from pyodbc, since that is missing a bunch of functions from ODBC3.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to access TimesTen via a Python module is using [cx_Oracle](https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/).

cx_Oracle uses an OCI based driver. 
TimesTen supports OCI and you can connect via tnsnames.ora or the Easy Connect naming method like you would for an Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0):

@ScalableDBDoug, would you mind providing the python code snippet? I tried using cx_Oracle in python script but was getting error message:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact
```

Here is my code snippet:

```py
import cx_Oracle

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('TTSERVER',TTPORT,service_name='TTSERVICE');
print(dsn_tns)
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('USER', 'PASS', dsn_tns)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM MYTABLE""")
for record in cursor:
    print("Values:", record)
```

As a workaround I'm using UnixODBC and pyodbc to query the timesten database for now, But would like to use the native cx_Oracle module to access timesten.

Thanks,